# Dynamic Input Width with Labels

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm attempting to create dynamic width field inputs so that they stretch to the width of the div.

If there are two inputs on a single line, they will dynamically split the space available to fill 100% of the div.

If there is only one input on a line, it will fill the whole width.

The issue is that the label width and the input width are both unknown (responsive web design).

It's surprising that this is difficult to do with how common I'm sure it must be.

http://imagepaste.nullnetwork.net/img/1339700574Screen%20Shot%202012-06-14%20at%203.04.59%20PM.png

Comment: Yes, please see the image link.  That's as close as I could get.  I'm not looking for someone to do it for me.  I'm looking for a concept to research to see if this is even worth the trouble.

Comment: Are you ok using javascript / js library as an option ?

Comment: I'm developing with Ruby, Rails, jQuery.  So yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it possible, using jQuery, you can count the number of input elements inside a div, and adjust the width of the elements accordingly.

You can use `length` or `size()` so determine the number of elements, and then set the css to do the same

Here is a rough mock-up : http://jsfiddle.net/6CqKK/

Answer (score 0):

Some quick testing with JsFiddle (BTW, please post example code so we can see what you've done so far) gives me this:

```
<div style="width:100%;border:1px solid gold;">
    <div style="width:100%; border:1px solid silver;">
        <div style="float:left;width:45%">In1 <input style="width:90%;"></div>
        <div style="float:right;width:45%">In2 <input style="width:90%;"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;width:100%;border:1px solid silver;">
        <div style="float:left;width:20%">In1 <input style="width:90%;"></div>
        <div style="float:left;width:20%">In2 <input style="width:90%;"></div>
        <div style="float:right;width:20%">In3 <input style="width:90%;"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="clear:both">&nbsp;</div>

<table style="width:100%;border:1px solid gold;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:49%;border:1px solid silver;">In1 <input style="width:60%"></td>
        <td style="width:49%;border:1px solid silver;">In2 <input style="width:60%"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table style="width:100%;border:1px solid gold;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:29%;border:1px solid silver;">In1 <input style="width:60%"></td>
        <td style="width:29%;border:1px solid silver;">In2 <input style="width:60%"></td>
        <td style="width:29%;border:1px solid silver;">In2 <input style="width:60%"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

See it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9BLdS/). As you can see neither version is quite right but, as usual, table based layouts are more robust, Even after messing about [further](http://jsfiddle.net/9BLdS/14/), I couldn't get the three column set to work properly but using the tables is easy enough.

The main thing is to work out the percentages. As you are using JS, this should be fairly straight forward. However, if the labels can also vary, this will make calculations rather more complex.